# In GitLab's CI/CD system how do I prevent a job from running if it's in my fork and only allow it to run if its a merge to the main repo?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, branch, git-fork

I have a job in my `gitlab-ci.yml` like

```
build and push:
  stage: push
  only:
  - master
  script:
  - gcloud docker -- push $IMAGE_TAG
```

The idea being that it should only run if the branch is master, but I also only want it to run if the repo is `app/` and not `dave/`

[The docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) say

> The repository path can be used to have jobs executed only for the parent repository and not forks:

```
job:
  only:
    - branches@gitlab-org/gitlab-ce
```

but I can't get this to work. If our gitlab server is `gitlab.myco.io` and the app is `app/my-project-name` I figured I could put

```
job:
  only:
    - branches@gitlab-myco-io/app/my-project-name/master
```

but that does not seem to work.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to configuration below. You don't need it to run for all branches (only master branch) and that too of the original repo.

```
job:
  only:
    - master@app/my-project-name
```

Comment: Are you sure app/my-project-name is your git repo name? Or is it just my-project-name?

Comment: hmm actually the repo name and the project name are subtly different.  retrying....

Comment: Okay I have double checked this and still no luck.  `app` is the name of the `group` and `my-project-name` is the name of the project so the repo is in `https://gitlab.myco.io/app/my-project-name` (not the real name of the project obvs.)

Comment: @DaveSag Is it a self hosted gitlab instance? Can you try `master@app/my-project-name` ?

Comment: Yes it is self-hosted (by client). I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: alas no that made no difference

Comment: Okay now it's working.  It turned out that the project name and the repo path were slightly different for some odd reason.

Comment: @DaveSag Yea I figured, thats why I asked you earlier on the repo name. :)

Comment: if you could update your answer I'll tick it as the correct. The correct answer was to change to `master@app/my-project-name`

Comment: @DaveSag Updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Building on [privateomega's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56071002/4228798), since [only / except are being deprecated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic), the modern alternative with `rules`, also supporting generic main branch names, would be something like:

```yaml
job:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE == "app" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
```

See also https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/04/22/gitlab-12-10-released/#auto-devops-and-secure-configuration-templates-are-changing-to-%60rules%60-instead-of-%60only/except%60